# Why is custom UICollectionViewCell's outlet nil after scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I wrote a custom component that uses **`UICollectionView`** and this **`UICollectionView`** has also custom **`UICollectionViewCell`** class with **`xib`** file. 
In my **`UIViewController`** class **`viewDidLoad`** method, I send a web service request and after the response comes I register my custom **`UICollectionViewCell`** with this code;

```
    let bundle = Bundle(for: MyCustomCellClass.self)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "MyCustomCellClass", bundle: bundle)
    collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MyCustomCellClass.reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.reloadData()
```

Then in my **`UICollectionView`** **`cellForItemAt`** I dequeue cell with this way;

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: MyCustomCellClass.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCellClass else {
        fatalError("Cell should be registered")
    }

    let carObject = myList![indexPath.row])!
    cell.carImageView.image = carObject.image

    return cell
}
```

The problem exists **after I scroll**, the car image has gone. That is because my **`MyCustomCellClass`** image view outlet becomes suddenly **nil**.
I can't find the solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code in your cell class?  In `prepareForReuse` in particular?

Comment: Why not register the cell before the request, and then refresh the cell after the request is completed.

Comment: I tried registering cell in viewDidLoad then reloading the UICollectionView after the response comes, but still same problem, in fact the cells UI are mixed after scrolling, like first cell's image turns into the image that belongs to the fourth cell.@Nullable

Comment: @Paulw11 no I don't have a magical code in my custom cell class.

Comment: Can you show how you load the data and the images

Comment: @Paulw11You are right, I remove some outlets according to the cell data, I removed that code and started to use isHidden, now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Right. Cells are reused from a pool when you scroll, so you can't alter their structure